# How do I make text hover?

Tags: html, css, web

http://cdpn.io/jLAJg
Can someone please teach me how to make text appear when you hover the mouse on each pic? (I only finished the Codecademy Web fundamentals course. The site I posted is basically all I know in regards to web coding)

Comment: Heya, welcome to Stack Overflow. There are a few issues with your post that may cause it to receive some downvotes and get closed. Typically a question is expected to have some code and attempted solutions, shared research, and why your solutions didn't work. See [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some help. (PS. An obfuscated link isn't typically well received either.)

Answer (score 2):

You can add `title` attribute to your element.

```
<img src="something" alt="Hover to see the tooltip!" title="Tooltip!" />
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/msek4/1/)

If you want more custom tooltips, you can use [google search](https://www.google.fi/search?q=jquery%20tooltip), you find lots of good javascript/jquery examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this, which is pretty simple:

(I've updated the codepen to have multiple boxes)

[<kbd>codePen</kbd>](http://codepen.io/BeatAlex/pen/vwEdf) - [<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/v7aVC/)

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  <a href="http://google.co.uk">Click Me!</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box{
  background:red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
}

.box:hover a{
  bottom:10px;
  opacity:1;
}

a{
  transition:all .4s;
  -webkit-transition:all .4s;
  background:blue;
  color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  text-align:center;
  opacity:0;
}
```

It uses pure CSS so there's no external libraries needed.

Obviously you'll have to change the text, but it will work for multiple at the same time.

Comment: +1 for CSS only, no doubt someone will mention `jQuery` :)

Comment: Here is a fiddle -http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/scp8X/- that uses all of the techniques above, and adds the jQuery .hover and jQuery .hover and .animate. Just building on the excellent answers above.

Comment: @TimSPQR that link is broken. Also, the code is broken. :(

Comment: Ok, working now. http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/scp8X/1/ - A pesky parenthesis snuck into the code :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one thing, you could use the `title` attribute on each image. That way, a tooltip with the given text will show up when you hover your mouse over the element.

Example:

```
<img src="images/penguin.jpg" alt="Cute penguin">
```